# I want to check the html text as a condition, but how should I deal with &nsbp or &#160?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

This is what the page source snippet looks like:

```
<div style="TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; MARGIN-RIGHT: 0pt" align="justify">
<font style="DISPLAY: inline; TEXT-DECORATION: underline">ITEM 1A.&#160;&#160;&#160;RISK FACTORS</font></font></div>
```

This is what I am trying to do.

```
for item in page_soup.find_all('div'):
    if "ITEM 1A. RISK FACTORS" in item.text:
        do something...
```

However, it does not identify the whole string. If I do `if "ITEM 1A." in item.text`, it works in that case. But I want to check the condition with the complete text "ITEM 1A. RISK FACTORS"

Comment: If this is a string, then you need to clean it like ```"ITEM A.&#160;&#160;&#160;RISK FACTORS".replace("&#160;","")``` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case white spaces are introduced by means other than `&#160;` (such as `&nbsp;`) you can try

```
for item in page_soup.find_all('div')::
   if "ITEM 1A." in item.text and "RISK FACTORS" in item.text:
     do something...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in page_soup.find_all('div'):
    if "ITEM 1A. RISK FACTORS" in item.text.replace('&#160;',''):
        do something...
```

try thinking simple

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer that uses Regex

```
import re


for item in page_soup.find_all('div'):
    if re.search('ITEM.*RISK FACTORS', item.text):    
        do something...
```